# Why does performing a manipulation on a variable affect the DOM in Vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript

If I want to append some HTML (a `<p>` tag in this case) to an element in Vanilla JS then it seems I have to do this:

```
const $Element = document.getElementById("ElementID");
$Element.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", "<p></p>");
```

That works great, but what I don't understand is if I'm storing a reference to `#ElementID` in a `$Element` variable, why does manipulating the variable cause the DOM to update?

Say I wanted to do many changes to `$Element` like first add a `<h1>` tag and then a `<h2>` and then multiple `<p>` tags. I would like all of them to be done first and then ask JS to update the DOM instead of it doing it in real-time. Is that even possible in Vanilla JS?

Comment: Look at the type of the variable you have; do `console.log(typeof $Element)`. It's not a string variable. It's a reference to a DOM element. Calling methods on DOM element references make changes to the DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish what you are looking for you can always use `cloneNode` to clone the element you want to change, make the changes, then replace it in the dom with `replaceChild` on the element's parent.

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('#target');

var clone = elem.cloneNode(true);
clone.innerHTML = "TeST";
clone.style.backgroundColor = "red";

elem.parentNode.replaceChild(clone, elem);
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

> I'm storing a reference to #ElementID in a $Element variable, why does manipulating the variable cause the DOM to update?

Because that's how references work. You can place the same reference in any number of variables, you still only have one object, and if you modify that object, the other variables "pointing" to that reference will reflect those changes, because they are all simply handles to the same object in memory.

If you want to batch changes, make a *new* DOM element, prepare it, and then add it to the DOM.

Comment: I would not only have to make a new DOM element and prepare it but also remove the existing DOM element before appending the new one. Isn't that expensive to do?

Comment: @volumeone You would replace the existing element, yes. Define "expensive". Are you looking for a zero-cost method for updating the DOM? It doesn't exist.